# Attribute selector in XPath specification (in SAS)

Tags: xml, xpath, sas

I want to use SAS to read in a XML file together with a XMLMap like this:

```
filename xml "/data/file.xml";
filename map "/data/map.xml";
libname xml xmlv2 xmlmap=map;
```

Is it possible to use a XPath specification like

```
/team/name[@type="first"]/value
```

After trying some variations and reading the SAS Documentation, it seems like the selector is only allowed for the last level to be selected.

A XML snippet could look like this

```
<team>
 <name type="first">
  <value>First Name</value>
 </name>
 <name type="last">
  <value> Last Name </value>
 </name>
</team>
```

Greetings

Comment: The XPath specification certainly allows your expression (even in XPath 1.0). I can't speak for the SAS implementation.

Comment: To my knowledge, SAS uses indeed xslt version 1.

Comment: You can import a complete XML in multiple (way too much) tables, using the defaults of XML mapper. You can do this using the Schema too. Then you can merge/join the tables to get the one table you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no, based on many attempts and the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/engxml/p0f31xwrf0ti5fn11za2wn3929c8.htm).

Here is the key quote where they inform us that only a very small subset of XPath is supported:

> CAUTION
>
> These forms are the only XPath forms that the XML engine supports. If you use any other valid W3C form, the results will be unpredictable.

Then they list two "forms" where you can either select an element (its PCDATA) or an attribute.

You can make that selection conditional, but it must be conditional on the element itself and not an ancestor. Why that is true is anyone's guess.

If your XML looked like this:

```xml
<team>
 <name type="first">
  First Name
 </name>
 <name type="last">
  Last Name
 </name>
</team>
```

You could parse it using the element form like so:

```
/team/name[@type="first"]
```

But the enclosing `<value>` tag makes using the XMLMap utility futile.